# Inserting data from json file to mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB and for practice i downloaded the restaurant data from mongodb site. I am using windows OS and mongo is installed properly.
Now, I want to insert all the restaurant documents ( i.e json data) to mongodb. I am using cmd and tried this command

```
 mongoimport --db test --collection restaurants --drop --file ~/downloads/primer-dataset.json
```

but it failed and got the message that

```
 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:4
```

How to solve this error? Please help me because I couldn't find satisfactory answer even after spending too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongoimport` must be run from the Windows command prompt, not the mongo shell.

Comment: @siddharthpal Are you sure? That's the error you get if you try and run that command within the mongo shell.